# Allow user to enter 'enter (/n)' along with few other special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am applying regex check in javascript for what all a user can enter.

```
  var check=/^[\n\*\'\/.\+(),:_a-zA-Z0-9 @]*$/.test(body);
  if (check != true)
  {
  alert("not allowed");
  }
```

only *()_+@',./ special characters and all letters, digits and spaces are allowed, but its working fine for everything except enter (`\n`).

Comment: Newlines on some OS's include `\r`. Include that and you should be fine.

Comment: Where does the user enter that? Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign in regex means the end of a line. Remove that and you'll be good to go.

Comment: And the `^`  means the start of the line and the `*` means matched 0 to infinity times. What's your point? Essentially he's just checking if the entire string matches only these characters.

Comment: The match ends at $ (end of the line) so this regex won't match strings that contain \n (new line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiline regex like this:

```
^([\*\(\)\+\@',\.\/\w\s]|(\n|\r))*$
```

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION

  ^                        the beginning of the string

  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):

    [\*\(\)\+\@',\.\/\       any character of: '\*', '\(', '\)',
    w\s]                     '\+', '\@', ''', ',', '\.', '\/', word
                             characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")

   |                        OR

    (                        group and capture to \2:

      \n                       '\n' (newline)

     |                        OR

      \r                       '\r' (carriage return)

    )                        end of \2

  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)

  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yN9L8/)
eg.

```
var regex = /^([\*\(\)\+\@',\.\/\w\s]|(\n|\r))*$/
var check = regex.test(body);
if (check != true)
{
    alert("not allowed");
}
```